# Can we write a custom angularjs service that is available to all modules but instantiated only once

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to write a custom angularjs service that is available to all modules on a page but instantiated only once?

Very much like the global services e.g. $http provided by Angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In AngularJS services are singletons by default, see [the developer guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services) for details.

Comment: That works if all modules are in the same application but if I have multiple applications (bootstrapped using angular.bootstrap) then the services seem to be instantiating once for each application.